# Netbeans: How to build .jar file attached with external .jar library?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, external

In Netbeans 7.1 when I've attached a external blucove.jar library , built it and the output file is app.jar.When I'm running the app.jar from CMD using : java -jar app.jar ,the external library not working.

Is there any solution?

Comment: If the external library is in the same (or a near) path you could pack the relative path into the MANIFEST.MF in META-INF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable "Copy Dependent Libraries" in the project properties:

[image]

Once you have enabled that your `dist` directory should contain:

```
app.jar
lib/blucove.jar
```

Comment: This box was already checked for me in Netbeans. And I have dist/lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar and dist/TargetJar.jar. When I send out the jar file to use on OSX, it throws ClassNotFoundException.